# Telegram Bot EditMessageText is not working

Tags: java, telegram-bot, inline, message, edit

I found out a message sent via **AnswerInlineQuery** can be edited by **EditMessageText()** in *"supergroup"* chats only.

The created group by default has the *"group"* type, but after changing any settings, it changes to "supergroup" (I read this from the documentation).

Next, I changed the chat where I couldn't edit the message sent via AnswerInlineQuery to "supergroup" and it worked. There is no information about the group type in the telegram client itself.

Also, the message sent via **AnswerInlineQuery** to the *"private"* type chat is not editable too. Haven't tried channels.

And messages sent via **SendMessage()** are edited without problems in any chat type, the main thing is to catch the messageID.

Is it library limitation, or it's not possible for API in common?

````
    private final TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot(System.getenv("TG_BOT_TOKEN"));

    long chatID;
    int messageID;

    public void listen() {
        this.bot.setUpdatesListener(updates -> {
            updates.forEach(this::process);
            return UpdatesListener.CONFIRMED_UPDATES_ALL;
        });
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void process(Update update) {

        Message message = update.message();
        InlineQuery inlineQuery = update.inlineQuery();

        BaseRequest request = null;

        if (message != null && message.viaBot() != null) {
            chatID = message.chat().id();
            messageID = message.messageId();
            request = new EditMessageText(chatID, messageID, String.valueOf(update.message().messageId()));
        }
        if (inlineQuery != null) request = new AnswerInlineQuery(inlineQuery.id(), new InlineQueryResultArticle("id", "title", "text"));
        if (request != null) bot.execute(request);
    }
}```
````